# Solr MoreLikeThisComponent: Return similarity value for result documents

Tags: solr, morelikethis

I execute a SOLR search and return related documents using the MoreLikeThisComponent (passing mlt=true and related parameters via URL). How can I get the similarity value for the similar documents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the score field back. Add the `score` field to the `fl` parameter.

If you wanna normalize, add the `match_include` parameter, and normalize the scores against the one of the document you submitted.

See http://docs.lucidworks.com/display/solr/MoreLikeThis for more details on each parameters.

Comment: Thanks, it works! But the score field is not documented on the page you liked to. So where should I have found it on my own? There is quite some Solr documentation, but it seems to have quite some gaps!?

Comment: could you elaborate on the "score" field mentioned. Where can this info be found?